# How can I access an Interbase (.IB) database using RubyOnRails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, interbase

I have a database in Interbase and I want to access it directly from my Rails app using ActiveRecord. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

There is a gem called [activerecord-interbase-adapter](http://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-interbase-adapter) although I haven't used it.

Comment: You mean the link I originally referenced or the gem itself? I have just updated the link.